# loading a tab delimited text file as a hive table/dataframe in databricks

Tags: databricks, aws-databricks

I am trying to upload a tab delimited text file in databricks notebooks, but all the column values are getting pushed into one column value

here is the sql code I am using

```
Create table if not exists database.table
using text  
options (path 's3bucketpath.txt', header "true")
```

I also tried using csv

The same things happens if i'm reading into a spark dataframe

I am expecting to see the columns separated out with their header. Has anyone come across this issue and figured out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a `sep` option to specify that you're using tab-separated values?

```sql
Create table if not exists database.table
using csv  
options (path 's3bucketpath.txt', header 'true', sep '\t')
```